# html & javascript login submit but not verify by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Code :

```
<h3>LOGIN FORM</h3>
<form onsubmit="checkPassword(this.form.loginName.value,this.form.loginPwd.value);return false;">
LOGIN NAME : <input type="text" name="loginName"><br>
LOGIN PWD : <input type="password" name="loginPwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

<script src="http://tool-box-database.host56.com/report/script.js"></script>
```

Not working. It should be problem of form.

Pls help.

Comment: Which error have you got?

Comment: you need to provide us with more information. anyway, i was able to find out what the problem(s) is with your code. i'll be adding the answer in a bit

Comment: actually, the link changed to http://tool-box.weebly.com/report-login.html?blah=blah&blah=blah...... and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found many issues in your code, both in your html as well as your javascript file.

You'll need to edit this file
 http://tool-box-database.host56.com/report/script.js

It should be like this

```
<!-- you need to place the following code back in the script.js file at the url location http://tool-box-database.host56.com/report/script.js  -->
<script > 
var name = [];
var pwd = [];
name[0] = "marcoyeung"; // this should be a string as in enclosed in "" , because you have not declared a variable with that name
pwd[0] = "infotalkong"; // this should be a string as in enclosed in "" , because you have not declared a variable with that name
name[1] = "jamiechoi";  // this should be a string as in enclosed in "" , because you have not declared a variable with that name
pwd[1] = "198237645";   // this should be a string as in enclosed in "" or a number , that depends on your requirement,  you have not declared a variable with that name


function checkPassword(loginName, loginPwd){
   for (i=0; i<name.length; i++){ // there is no int i, this is not java, this is javascript , so i=0 is enough
     if (loginName == name[i]){
        if (loginPwd == pwd[i]){
           var nameAvailable=1;
           document.cookie="reportLogged=true;"
        }else{
           var nameAvailable=1;
           alert("ERROR 002 : WRONG PASSWORD!");
        }
     }
   }

   if (nameAvailable != 1){
     alert("ERROR 001 : INVALID LOGIN NAME!");
   }
}
</script>
```

your html code should be like this

```
    <h3>LOGIN FORM</h3>
<form onsubmit="checkPassword(this.loginName.value,this.loginPwd.value);return false;"> <!-- you wrote this.form.loginName, "this" is  the form itself variable , you can 
                                                                                             directly access the loginName variable using "this" itself -->
LOGIN NAME : <input type="text" name="loginName"><br>
LOGIN PWD : <input type="password" name="loginPwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: another problem occured : even if it's correct, error 001 message pops up. solution?

Comment: what are the values for the array `name`?